# Android: searchView does not remove text when I click on cross button

Tags: android, listview, searchview

This is the picture of the searchView and of the listView.
When I start searching for instance the Title: **Adeeieva** it updates the listView.
But when I tap on the cross button it does not bring the listView it hangs there.
What I want is that when I click on the cross button it recreate the listView and brings on its initial state.
Can someone help me please?
[image]
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;
    Books booksObj;
    BooksAdapter booksAdapter;
    BooksAdapter_1 mBooksAdapter;
    String url="http://google.com";
    Gson gson;
    AsyncHttpClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(MainActivity.this, url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                String responsestr=new String(responseBody);
                gson=new Gson();

                booksObj=gson.fromJson(responsestr, Books.class);

                mBooksAdapter= new BooksAdapter_1(MainActivity.this, booksObj.getBooks());
                listView.setAdapter(mBooksAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView description=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.book_description);
                TextView title_= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
                TextView isbn_= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_isbn);



                String _title=title_.getText().toString();
                String _isbn=isbn_.getText().toString();
                String _description=description.getText().toString();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("title", _title);
                myIntent.putExtra("isbn", _isbn);
                myIntent.putExtra("description", _description);

                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });

        SearchView sv= (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                mBooksAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

BookAdapter_1

```
public class BooksAdapter_1 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private List<Books.BooksEntity> mBooksitem;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    BooksFilter mBooksFilter;

    public BooksAdapter_1(Context context, List<Books.BooksEntity> mBooksitem){
        this.mContext= context;
        this.mBooksitem= mBooksitem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mBooksitem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mBooksitem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_layout_item, parent, false);

        Books.BooksEntity item=(Books.BooksEntity)getItem(position);
        TextView id=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_id);
        TextView title=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        TextView description=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_description);
        TextView isbn=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_isbn);
        ImageView book_url=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.book_url);

        id.setText(String.valueOf(item.getId()));
        title.setText("Title: "+item.getTitle());
        description.setText("Description: "+item.getDescription());
        isbn.setText("isbn: "+item.getIsbn());

        String imageUrl=item.getCover_url();
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).into(book_url);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(mBooksFilter==null)
            mBooksFilter= new BooksFilter();
        return mBooksFilter;
    }

    private class BooksFilter extends Filter{
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results= new FilterResults();

            if(constraint==null || constraint.length()==0){
                results.values=mBooksitem;
                results.count=mBooksitem.size();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Books.BooksEntity> filteredBooks= new ArrayList<Books.BooksEntity>();

                for(Books.BooksEntity b: mBooksitem){
                    if(b.getDescription().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
                        filteredBooks.add(b);
                    }
                }
                results.values=filteredBooks;
                results.count=filteredBooks.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mBooksitem=(ArrayList<Books.BooksEntity>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your close button click event code

Comment: I don't have it. I did not create that code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **declare an action** for the close (x) button.

And if you want to clear the search text, you can just **set the search query to ""** = nothing.

You also have to **reset the custom adapters filter** and **notify** it that something has changed, in this case the search query.

```
sv.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {

            sv.setQuery("", false);

            mBooksAdapter.getFilter().filter(sv.getQuery());

            mBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did that but when I click on the close button nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried notifyDataSetChanged for the mBooksAdapter? Add mBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); below the sv.setQuery("", false);

Comment: If that is not enough, try adding mBooksAdapter.clear() above sv.setQuery("", false); - I just added all this to the code above.

Comment: mBooksAdapter.clear does not exist. And tried to put your code but it does not work. Nothing happens. Still the same result.

Comment: You are using custom adapters BooksAdapter and BooksAdapter_1, so you have to create the .clear() methods on those adapters if you haven't yet. Can you add the codes for BooksAdapter.java and BooksAdapter_1.java here?

Comment: I'm only using BooksAdapter_1. Code is added in the post

Comment: When you are using a custom adapter, you should declare the clear() method in the adapter. You could clear the list data and load it again, but I think it's easier to set the searchviews' filter again in the activity. So clicking the close button should set the query to "" and then set the filter to match the query. So replace the mBooksAdapter.clear(); with mBooksAdapter.getFilter().filter(query); and put the sv.setQuery before the getFilter. Check the code above.

Comment: I tried this but no success. No error message nothing.

Comment: How does the app react? When you type your search argument, does the list update and display the correct item or items? Is the search function working properly? Does the search text clear when pressing the close button?

Comment: yes it searchs correctly and update the ListView and yes if I click on the cross button it clears the text but does not refresh the ListView after clearing the text.